# C# file upload to Java EE server

Tags: java, c#, jakarta-ee

My problem is, that after uploading the content of file is `[object Object]`.

How can I upload a file properly?

Server:

```
package com.turbulence6th.servlets;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;

@WebServlet("/saveFile")
@MultipartConfig
public class SaveFile extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String webAppPath = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
    Part file = request.getPart("file");

    String filename = getFileName(file);
    InputStream is = file.getInputStream();

    String directoryPath = webAppPath + File.separator + "files";
    File directory = new File(directoryPath);

    if(!directory.exists()){
        directory.mkdir();
    }

    String filePath = directoryPath + File.separator + filename;

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
    int read = 0;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

    while ((read = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
        fos.write(bytes, 0, read);
    }
    fos.close();

}

private String getFileName(Part part) {
    for (String content : part.getHeader("content-disposition").split(";")) {
        if (content.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
            return content.substring(
                    content.indexOf('=') + 1).trim().replace("\"", "");
        }
    }
    return null;
}

}
```

Client:

```
 using (var wb = new WebClient())
 {
   wb.UploadFile("http://" + host + ":8080/saveFile", "POST", path);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any manipulations with `response`. Inside `doPost` you copy file content to the `request`. Is it what you want?

By the way - I don't see any reason to not use [copy()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/copy.html).